# Encoding string labels to integers for hierarchical mutli-class classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset, data-preprocessing

Currently working on a hierarchical classification task, where I give my model some text input and it tells me, which 3 categories it belongs to `(main category, sub category, leaf category)`.

My labels are currently a list of strings, but for my model I need them as integers between `0 to N-1` (N being the number of classes in this category level).

I managed to find a solution by using a dictionary and giving each string a number (encoding) and then another dictionary doing the opposite (decoding) to check what the predictions are.

It works, but I figured once I use another dataset, I would have to generate two dictionaries again.
I looked around and found these two classes from the sklearn preprocessing library: [`MultiLabelBinarizer()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and [`LabelEncoder()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html). It looks like what I would need, but I have no idea how to use it in combination with the hierarchies.

Would appreciate any kind of hints on how to use them or any other solution!

Comment: have you tried to_categorical